# CommandError: No model or app named in elastic search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Here I am creating indices for a django model using django_elasticsearch_dsl but getting error while creating the one. My django app name where the code lies is example_app

```
django_elasticsearch_dsl = 0.5.1
elasticsearch = 6.6.1
```

I have tried rebuilding indexes with some already existing indices that working prefectly fine and tried replacing the fields with the new model field and that also working fine. But when creating separate file throwing error.

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index, fields

from example_app.models import RandomTable

posts = Index('random_table')

@posts.doc_type
class ExampleDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = RandomTable
        fields = [
            'des',
            'quality',
            'con',
            'name',
            'prep',
            'sur_name',
            'issue_num'
          ]
```

when running the command python manage.py search_index --rebuild --models=example_app 
Actual output is  CommandError: No model or app named example_app
Expected output is creating index

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and found out that the file where `ExampleDocument` is declared should be named `documents.py`.

In your case `example_app/documents.py`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'example_app.apps.ExampleAppConfig' in settings?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that's already been added, no workaround